# Convert String Date to DateTime in flutter

Tags: flutter, datetime

[image]

How to convert RequireDate(String) to DateTime ?

Comment: As a general comment, it is really not a great idea to store a date as a string on a database. For a NoSql database it is  better stored as a milliseconds since epoch integer. Many databases support datetime fields. So, if you have design control of the db I would suggest storing the date as anything but a string. It makes working with it a lot easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`intl`](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for this. Based on the format of `RequiredDate`, design a `DateFormat` and call `parse` on the input.

```dart
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

void main() {
  print(DateFormat("dd/MMM/y").parse("31/Oct/2022"));
}
```

You could try this code on https://dartpad.dev as well, I tinkered it on it to design the solution.

[image]

Comment: Sir , it is not possible to use this method , I ment that "/" comes with this sign when date is coming from database . if it has came like this "2020:06:12 00:00" it can be convert with parse().

Comment: `DateFormat` is different class. Re-read and try my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use a datetime parse **DateTime RequireDate;**

```
RequireDate: DateTime.parse(RequireDate),
```

Comment: "/" comes with this sign when date is coming from database

Comment: The above answer by @TirthPatel is correct for your case. But if you don't want to use external packages, you could just change the date format in your database to be set to the **yyyy/mm/dd**  **'1969-07-20 20:18:04Z'**. That way, you can easily use the DateTime.Parse(1969-07-20 20:18:04Z).